# Dynamic feed using Jquery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a newbie question...

Look at the Recent Activity Panel of this website:

http://barcodehero.com/

Looking at the source code, I can see how they are animating the feed. But where are the ajax calls?  How can something like this be implemented. I am sure this is very easy. But not for me ..

Here's how they are animating their feed:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      var delay = 2500;
      var numCardsDownloaded = 200;
      var numCardsToShow = 5;
      var nextToShow = numCardsDownloaded - 1;


      function animateFeed() {
        toHide = (nextToShow + numCardsToShow) % numCardsDownloaded
        $('#activity'+nextToShow).remove().prependTo('#activity-list').slideDown(1000);
        $('#activity'+toHide).slideUp(1000);
        nextToShow = (nextToShow + numCardsDownloaded - 1) % numCardsDownloaded
        setTimeout('animateFeed()', delay);
      }    

      $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout('animateFeed()', delay);
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: what language are you using?  php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc?

Comment: I would like yo use it with php. I am not sure what they are using.

Comment: barcodehero looks like a rails site

Answer (score 0):

The site is not actually making any AJAX calls.  They have 200 "updates" loaded on their site and are just rotating them.  If you are looking for a simple way to make AJAX queries, check out http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: So, can I get 200 random "updates" from my server side and spit it out as HTML every time I load say..index.html page..and then use Jquery to animate it?

Comment: You can, but it's pretty lame, especially because this isn't that hard to do.  (The site probably does it for privacy issues).  If you want to use jQuery, check out the http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ command.  Simply give it a url, and it will return the contents of that url.

Answer (score 0):

They are not making ajax calls to update the list. Check the source code and you will see all the posts in HTML, they are all just hidden and then animated. You can find out more about jQuery (the library used to animate) which also include ajax functions at: http://www.jquery.com